# JavaMelody - Monitoring of sql requests and of jdbc connections in GlassFish v3+

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4.1, java-melody

I want to use JavaMelody to monitor the SQL requested by a Glassfish Application Server. There are step-by-step instructions on https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#monitoring-of-sql-requests-and-of-jdbc-connections-in-glassfish-v3, but the second step does not work for me.

The instruction is:

> In the GlassFish admin console, rename your JDBC Resource (DataSource)
>   from "jdbc/MyDataSource" to "jdbc/MyDataSource_uncached" for example

I can't find any way to edit rename the JDBC Resource.

The following screenshot shows the JDBC data source tab of the Glassfish Admin console:
[Edit JNDI Name of a JDBC Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdTKX.png)

Do you know how to rename JNDI Name of a JDBC Resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is no command in the Glassfish UI to rename the JDBC Resource.

I have added more precision in the doc:

> In the GlassFish admin console, rename your JDBC Resource (DataSource)
>   from "jdbc/MyDataSource" to "jdbc/MyDataSource_uncached" for example,
>   **by creating a new identical JDBC Resource then deleting the old one**